# ユーザーインターフェースのプルダウンで、最初の1回しか計算が走らない

Tags: java

以下のプログラムでは、プルダウンでUSD to JPYを選ぶと米ドルから日本円に換金され、CNY to JPYを選ぶと、人民元から日本円に換金されるのですが、一回ずつ選んだ後は、最後に選んだ通貨のプログラムしか実行されません。

例えば1回目でUSDを選ぶと米ドルの計算になり、その後CNYを選ぶと人民元の計算になるが、その後は米ドルを選んでも、最後に選んだ人民元の計算しかされない (逆も然り)。

どうしてこのようになってしまうのでしょうか？ `for` 文等で回していないからでしょうか？

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rate2 extends JFrame {
    int n;
    JMenuBar mbar = new JMenuBar();
    JTextField f0 = new JTextField("");
    JButton b0 = new JButton("実行");

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Input a number and press the button.");
    JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Currency"); 
    JMenuItem item01 = new JMenuItem("USD to JPY");
    JMenuItem item02 = new JMenuItem("CNY to JPY");
    boolean a=false;
    boolean b=false;

    public Rate2() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setTitle("menu sample");
        setLayout(null);

        add(f0); f0.setBounds(100, 50, 50, 30);
        add(b0);b0.setBounds(150,50,50,30);
        mbar.add(menu1);setJMenuBar(mbar);
        menu1.add(item01);menu1.add(item02);

        add(l1);l1.setBounds(150,140,150,100);
        //pack(); 
        setSize(400, 300);

        item01.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                a=true;
            }
        });

        item02.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                b=true;
            }
        });

        b0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if(a){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());

                Dollar d1=new Dollar(n);
                Double d2=d1.Ex();
                l1.setText(n+"USDは"+d2+"円");}
                else if(b){Double n=Double.parseDouble(f0.getText());

                CNY c1=new CNY(n);
                Double c2=c1.Ex2();

                l1.setText(n+"人民元は"+c2+"円");}

                else{return;} 

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Rate2().setVisible(true);
    }

    static class Dollar{
        int d=100;

        Double dl;Double n;

        public Dollar(Double n){
            this.n=n;
        }

        public Double Ex(){
            return dl=d*n;
        }
    }

    static class CNY {
        Double cn;
        int c=15;
        Double n;
        public CNY(Double n){
            this.n=n;
        }

        public Double Ex2(){
            return cn=c*n;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実行ボタンを押したときの条件判定が次のようになっていますが、一旦`a`が`true`になった場合、`false`に戻ることはないので常にドル円計算になっています。
(つまり、質問文に書かれている状況説明は正確ではありません)

```java
b0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (a) {
            // ドル円計算
        } else if (b) {
            // 元円計算
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

メニューを選んだ際、反対側のフラグを`false`に設定してやれば所望の動作になるかと思います。

```java
item01.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        a = true;
        b = !a;
    }
});

item02.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        b = true;
        a = !b;
    }
});
```